# I can not populate JQuery Autocomplete input with a json request to cakephp

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, cakephp

I am using JQuery autocomplete to send a json request to my cakephp application, the javascript code is from [http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote)

```
  $(function() {
    function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#tag-string" )
  // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
      .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      })
      .autocomplete({
        source:function(request, response){ 
          $.getJSON("/articles/getTags/" + request.term + ".json", {
            term : extractLast(request.term)
          }, response);
       },
        search: function() {
          // custom minLength
          var term = extractLast( this.value );
          if ( term.length < 1 ) {
            return false;
          }
        },
        focus: function() {
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          var terms = split( this.value );
          // remove the current input
          terms.pop();
          // add the selected item
          terms.push( ui.item.value );
          // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
          terms.push( "" );
          this.value = terms.join( ", " );
          return false;
        }
      });
  });(jQuery);
```

if i run the XMLHttpRequests on the chrome js console (where "c" is the term to search for)

```
$.getJSON("/articles/getTags/c.json")
```

i get this response text:

> responseText: "{↵ "tags": [↵ {↵ "tag": "Calles"↵ },↵ {↵ "tag": "Circulacion"↵ },↵ {↵ "tag": "cognicion"↵ },↵ {↵ "tag": "Creatividad"↵ }↵ ]↵}"

but the input field does not populate with this values.
This is what i get (i've uploaded an image because is the easiest way to explaint it) on the "Tag String" input field
[image: screen]

Comment: The screenshot you shared, I see something is appending to your input field, may by the results, but are not visible due to CSS issue maybe. Try inspecting the input field.

Comment: thanks @MotsManish, nothing strange found on the input field or the css style sheet. Will keep trying

Comment: Please write an answer and accept it, don't edit the question to say "solved".

Comment: @RaulMagdalenaCatala cool, but please make the answer meaningful. The response your code generated isn't in the question (unless it's that responseText thing - format it to the actual response if so), the variable you've used in the answer isn't in the question. Thanks for actioning my firs comment.

Answer (score 0):

finally solved.
the json response send to jquery autocomplete must be formated with "value" and "label".

```
var ac = [
{
    label: "One Thing",
    value: "One-Thing"
},
{
    label: "Two Thing",
    value: "Two-Thing"
},
```

]